# Big performance drop on own program

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cpu, performance, c#

I am not sure that this right site Stack Exchange. Tell me which one if it's wrong.

I have my own program (C#, WinForms) and two computers with CPUs:

1. Intel Core i5-2320, 3200 MHz (Windows 7)
2. Intel Celeron G1820 2700 MHz (Windows 10)

The program works in conjunction with the Access database (Entity Framework Core). For example, load a number of records to display in a table, add, update, and delete records.

My problem is performance. There is no problem for the first computer. Here is part of log:

```
Load page: 00:00:01.8143480
LoadSetData(): 00:00:00.1475554
===! Load time: 00:00:02.3864354 !===
Update() contract: 00:00:00.1656815
Update() contract: 00:00:00.0436293
```

The second computer does strange things. Can do so:

```
Load time: 00:00:17.8201432
DeleteSubject(): 00:00:25.7574691
Update() contract: 00:00:10.1656815
```

And can so:

```
Load time: 00:00:02.3210213
DeleteSubject(): 00:00:00.4818238
Update() contract: 00:00:00.1836919
```

The program code is the same in all cases. The only difference is the bit width. The first computer starts x86 (because Office Access x86 is installed). The second computer is x64. Compile through Visual Studio.

I can't understand why such a significant drop in performance. It's like something's taking over the entire processor. Not letting my program work. But in a different times, giving work correctly.

I don't think it has anything to do with the program code. After all the second computer can adequately process my program. According to the logs.

What could be the reason for this problem?

For example, I can give a typical database access code to give an understanding that this is not a "heavy" task for a large amount of time.

```
internal bool DeleteContract(int id)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    bool result = true;

    try
    {
        using (ModelContext model = new ModelContext())
        {
            Contracts c = model.Contracts.Single(x => x.Id == id);
            model.Remove(c);
            model.SaveChanges();
        }
        Count--;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
        ShowMessage.Error("some text");
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();
    logger.Debug("DeleteContract(): {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly and entirely environmental. who knows whats happening, i.e that *celeron* could be thermal throttling, it could have virus scanners or what ever else. There is nothing in your code that says this is a code problem. Also it should be known this type of test is problematic and not the best way to benchmark, there could be differences in the DB and how it spins up or any number of settings thereof

Comment: Not to mention that the Celeron is dual-core, while the i5 is a quad with core boosting. Also Windows 10 out-of-the-box is somewhat "busier" than 7. More load on less power might explain the spotty performance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target computer has antivirus. Sometimes firewall catches request to Microsoft. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002509/entity-framework-core-sends-a-request-to-microsoft-addresses-when-accessing-the) question. I don't know for what. It's slow down program. In other hand, open's Chrome with many tabs.